# Is Windows Authentication Impersonation dead in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

Found this bit while trying to find out why none of the impersonation stuff works.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#impersonation

> ASP.NET Core doesn't implement impersonation.

and

> RunImpersonated doesn't support asynchronous operations and shouldn't
>   be used for complex scenarios. For example, wrapping entire requests
>   or middleware chains isn't supported or recommended.

That sounds like a no-go to me. Is it no longer practical to query the database as the end user?

Answer (score 4):

Starting with `.NET 5` there will be a [`WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonatedAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.runimpersonatedasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

For now, you have to stick with this ([remarks from the 3.1 docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.runimpersonated?view=netcore-3.1)):

> This method may be used reliably with the async/await pattern, unlike Impersonate. In an async method, this method may be used with an async delegate argument so that the resulting task may be awaited.

The `.NET Platform Extensions` for `System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity` for `5.0` are [currently in preview2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Security.Principal.Windows/5.0.0-preview.2.20160.6).
You can find the release date here: [Upcoming Ship Dates](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md#upcoming-ship-dates)